# Periodic stream not sending data

Tags: dart, flutter

In my Flutter app, I have a stream created using the `Stream.periodic` constructor (the `timeleft`, `minutes`, and `seconds` variables are defined in the surrounding context):

```
_countdown = Stream.periodic(
    Duration(seconds: timeLeft),
    (count) {
        var value = '$minutes : $seconds';
        if (seconds-- == 0) {
            seconds = 59;
            --minutes;
        }
        return value;
    },
);
```

Then I have a `StreamBuilder` that consumes the stream:

```
StreamBuilder<String>(
    stream: _countdown,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      String message;
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        message = 'Finito!';
      } else {
        message = snapshot.data;
      }

      if(snapshot.hasError)
        message = '${snapshot.error}';

      return Text(
        message ?? 'HOLD',
        style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context)
            .style
            .apply(fontSizeFactor: 3.0),
      );
    },
),
```

When I run my app, I only see `HOLD` on the screen, like the `snapshot.data` variable is null. When I debug my app, the function passed to the `Stream.periodic` constructor is never called. I have also verified that the `timeleft` variable is greater than 0. It is actually 360, so the stream should be sending a new value every second and displaying it.

Why are there no values coming through the stream?

**EDIT:** I accepted diegodeveloper's answer since that was correct. If you would like to see how I ended up implementing the timer with RxDart check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation of the `Stream.periodic` , you will find this  :

> Creates a stream that repeatedly emits events at [period] intervals.

So , if you are using 360 seconds as interval, you will have to wait 360 seconds in every change.

Change the `timeLeft` to one (to emit values every second), change your logic and it should work.

```
Stream.periodic(
    Duration(seconds: 1),
```

Comment: Ah yes I see. I misunderstood the documentation. I solved my problem by using observables instead of streams. If interested check my answer below.

Comment: Sure, you can do it using Observable but it is a external package.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a timer that stops at a certain time I ended up having to use RxDart and Observables. Here is my solution that creates a stream which emits a value every 1 seconds and stops after a given length of time.

```
_countdown = Observable.repeat((count) {
    var value = '${hours}h : ${minutes}m : ${seconds}s';

    if (--seconds < 0) {
      seconds = 59;
      --minutes;
    }

    if (minutes < 0) {
      if (hours > 0) {
        minutes = 59;
        --hours;
      } else {
        minutes = 0;
      }
    }

    if (count == 0)
      return Observable.just(value);
    else
      return Observable.timer(value, Duration(seconds: 1));
}, timeLeft + 2);
```